# How can I solve the TypeError

Tags: python, django

TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class UserAuthentication(obtain_auth_token):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['User']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response(token.key)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic] and how to create a [mre]. Please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.